# Google Places Autocomplete Implementation with existing search bar

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete

I am struggling to implement google autocomplete places with an existing search bar as seen down below. I have attached the index.html & searchBar.js code. This is part of my project but the only two files I have needed for the autocomplete implementation. My react app loads but autocomplete functionality in the location search bar does not.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
<!-- CSS Reset -->
<link href="./reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:300,500,600" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:600" rel="stylesheet">
<!--
  manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
  homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
-->
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
<!--
  Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
  It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
  Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

  Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
  work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
  Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
-->
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD11rNs1iAHIpmFOiAmPtdpMQNjp23_6uw&libraries=places&callback=initialize"></script>
<title>ravenous</title>
  </head>
<body>

<!-- This HTML file is a template.
  If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

  You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
  The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

  To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
  To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
-->
 <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>

import React from 'react';
import './SearchBar.css';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const google = window.google;

const sortByOptions = {
'Best Match': 'best_match',
'Highest Rated': 'rating',
'Most Reviewed': 'review_count',
'Distance From': 'distance'
};

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
 super(props);
this.state = {
  term: '',
  location: '',
  sortBy: 'best_match',

};
this.handleTermChange = this.handleTermChange.bind(this);
this.handleLocationChange = this.handleLocationChange.bind(this);
this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
this.handleEnterKeyPressed = this.handleEnterKeyPressed.bind(this);
}

searchYelp() {
this.props.searchYelp(
  this.state.term,
  this.state.location,
  this.state.sortBy
);
}

handleTermChange(event){
this.setState({term: event.target.value});
}

handleLocationChange(event){
this.setState({location: event.target.value});
}

handleSearch(event){
  this.props.searchYelp(this.state.term, this.state.location, this.state.sortBy);
}

getSortByClass(sortByOption){
if(sortByOption === this.state.sortBy){
  return 'active';
}
return '';

}

handleEnterKeyPressed(event) {
 if (event.key === "Enter") {
 this.searchYelp();
 }
```

}

```
handleSortByChange(sortByOptionValue) {
  this.setState({
    sortBy: sortByOptionValue
  }, () => {
    this.props.searchYelp(this.state.term, this.state.location, this.state.sortBy);
  });
}

renderSortByOptions() {
return Object.keys(sortByOptions).map(sortByOption => {
  let sortByOptionValue = sortByOptions[sortByOption];
  return <li key={sortByOptionValue} onClick={this.handleSortByChange.bind(this, sortByOptionValue)} className={this.getSortByClass(sortByOptionValue)} >{sortByOption} </li>;
});
}

initialize() {
 var input = document.getElementById('location');
 new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
```

}

```
render() {
return (
  <div className="SearchBar">
    <div className="SearchBar-sort-options">
      <ul>
        {this.renderSortByOptions()}
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div className="SearchBar-fields">
      <input placeholder="Search Businesses" onChange={this.handleTermChange} onKeyPress={this.handleEnterKeyPressed}/>
      <input id="location" placeholder="Where?" onChange={this.handleLocationChange} onKeyPress={this.handleEnterKeyPressed}/>
    </div>
    <div className="SearchBar-submit">
      <a onClick={this.handleSearch}>Go</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
 }
}




SearchBar.propTypes = {
searchYelp: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default SearchBar;
```